# Counting problem: How many triangles?

Tags: combinatorics

Sixteen points are on the sides of a $4\times 4$ grid so that the center portion of $2\times 2$ are removed. How many triangles are there in total that have vertices chosen from those remaining points and at least 1 interior angle equal to $45^{\circ}.$

Comment: could you maybe provide a drawing?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a square consisting of four corner dots and three dots evenly spaced along each side?

Comment: Is there any such triangle that does not have one of the edges adjacent to the 45 degree angle aligned to the grid?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You can count "by hand"; there are not so many. Don't forget these ones.

[image]

Comment: Can u compute clearly and what is the answer?